# Does page weight affect page latency?

Tags: web, latency

I know this is a topic one can debate or argue on, but I am putting it out anyways to find out what others have found out about this.

My inclination is that it should affect page latency. However, I am not sure how much it will affect it and if/how one can measure that.

Thanks!

Comment: Latency, no. Delay, yes.

Comment: @tdammers: "Latency" and "delay" pretty much mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If by "page weight" you mean the total size of the web-page (in kB), and by "page latency" you mean the time it takes for the page to completely display on the user's browser, then yes, of course one affects the other!

Comment: How much? How can one measure that? Is it possible to produce a graph for a page that says - if the page weight is reduced by X% then the page latency will improve by Y%?

Comment: @ajay: Simplistically, if your connection speed is *R* kB/s, and your page size is *N* kB, then it will take a minimum of *N/R* seconds to load your page.  Of course, there are many other factors which will affect how long it takes.